# Grabbing coordinates from Google Maps to add to a form

Tags: javascript, forms, api, google-maps, maps

I'm working on a form where I want the user to enter their current location using the GPS location in google maps.  I've read the Google Maps API documentation but I'm still a bit lost on how to integrate it all.  I would appreciate any help, JS is still pretty new to me and it hasn't been easy to learn.

This is the code I used from Google Maps API.

```
  var map, infoWindow;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 18.2208, lng: -66.5901},
      zoom: 7,
    });
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('Localización encontrada.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
        map.setCenter(pos);
      }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      });
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
  }

  function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                          'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                          'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
    infoWindow.open(map);
  }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAwnKnBH4qxyjHYkg3QlJP46-yG_o4QkSc&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: the code looks incompleted

Comment: I edited your post to align the code to be more easily readable, but it appears you are, at the very least, missing a closing `}` for your `handleLocationError` function.

Comment: edited to add complete code

Answer (score 0):

Its kind of hard to answer your question since we are missing some information. Is the Google maps imported in your project with the geolocation API? You can create an account and generate a key on https://console.cloud.google.com

After that, you'll need to call the initMap() after the page is done loading by adding the following code at the end of your Javascript.

```
(function(){
    initMap();
}());
```

From there, you can now get the value of the coordinates inside your initMap function and add them wherever you need them calling `pos.lat` and `pos.lng`.

```
infoWindow.setContent(pos.lat+' / '+pos.lng);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/SohRonery/q69ra78v/6/